# Tables Alignment

Tags: html, css

I need some help with aligning two tables together, i.e: having the columns line up.

The first table has the headers, and the second table has the rows displayed.  I'm doing this on ruby, so, I have to put the result in another table because the updating won't work otherwise(puts the data away from the parent table..)  Is there a way, that I can have the two tables align, so the data for every row lines up with each header column.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have fixed widths for the cells and make the widths be the same for both tables.  Also make sure that you have the table properites be the same (i.e. the cellpadding, cellspacing and table widths )

Comment: Good idea, the only thing is this is for a report, so the spaces between have to be constant...good idea, cheers

Answer (score 1):

can't you just remove the  closing tag for the header and remove the  opening tag for the content?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a great idea, HTML-wise. Heading cells and data cells should really be in the same table. Then you get the alignment for free.

> “ I'm doing this on ruby, so, I have to put the result in another table because the updating won't work otherwise”

Are you entirely sure there’s no way for Ruby to update an HTML table that has header cells? Really?

Comment: Yeah I understand, I'll re look at the API to figure out how to do it.. thanks